# Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRDatabase'

Tags: xcode, swift

I think it has to do with cocoapods but I've done everything other users have suggested regarding them.

[This is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvRVp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `import Firebase` in that file and add this to your Podfile:

```
Target 'YourProject’ do
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
end
```

Comment: Im getting the same eror

Comment: Make sure you call `pod install` in the terminal before. And of course, only open the XCWorkspace after